# Layout issues, not sure what's causing the problem

Tags: php, css, wordpress, layout, post

The page in question is here: http://www.audio-agent.com/wordpress/clients.

As you can see, the last post is indented instead of staying aligned to the left, as if there's an invisible post in the way. I've looked through with Firebug and can't seem to find anything taking up the space. The PHP used to generate this section of the page is as follows:

```
<div class="post-wrapper">

    <?php query_posts('showposts=100&category_name=Clients&order=asc&orderby=title'); ?>
    <?php while (have_posts()) : the_post(); ?>

    <div class="post_box">

        <div id="post-<?php the_ID(); ?>">

            <h4 class="hidden"><?php the_title(); ?></h4>
            <img src="<?php echo get_post_meta($post->ID, 'brand_img', true); ?>" />
            <?php the_content()?>

        </div><!--post-->

    </div><!--post_box-->

    <?php endwhile;?>
    <?php wp_reset_query(); ?>

</div><!--post-wrapper-->
```

Thanks for any help!

Comment: Looks good in IE8 at least ;)

Comment: Heh, well I guess that's a good thing. :) I probably should have specified, I'm looking at it in Firefox, Chrome and Safari on a Mac right now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you put a

```
<div style="clear:both;"></div>
```

before the last , it lines up properly.

I would say that since that last box is being pushed to the middle, that there are some little tweaks to the spacing you need to make for the boxes on the right.

However, the clear will fix your problem immediately.

Comment: This will be the best solution, thanks. I'll use Javascript to append a clear div after every third post.

Comment: @R.J.: If you're choosing to use this, you should do it using Wordpress/PHP. There's no reason to use Javascript to do it (except that it might be easier for you). What if Javascript is disabled? A server side solution is more robust.

Comment: @thirtydot: Honestly, Javascript is the only way I know how to do it. I'm pretty new to development... how would I pull this off with PHP or through Wordpress?

Comment: @R.J.: I don't know Wordpress well enough to answer that, unfortunately. If the owner of the site *can customize* the text inside those boxes (and it could be really long), then I guess doing this through JS works fine. If the text for all boxes is going to stay around the same length (like it is now), then my solution really is much easier and cleaner.

Comment: @thirtydot: Yeah, I would like to do it with your method, but I have to prepare for the site owner to write longer descriptions. :/ Thanks for your help!

Comment: @R.J.: I *could* write some iffy PHP to enclose each set of 3 divs inside another div tag, with a style of `overflow: hidden` (to "clear the floats"). This will do what you want, server side.

Comment: You could actually write some javascript to get the height of the tallest div (by looping through them all), then apply that height to all of the post_boxes.